# Updating multiple rows using a subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, subquery, sql-update

I have a summary table return data from a master table. I am trying to update some of the summary data from values in the master table as such:

```
update #summary
  set TopSpeed = CD.TopSpeed, SpeedTime = CD.TimeSent, SpeedDriver = CD.Driver
from
(
  select top 1 TopSpeed, TimeSent, Driver
  from CarData
  where CarData.VehicleId = #summary.VehicleId 
  and CarData.TimeSent between #summary.Start and #summary.Stop
  order by CarData.TopSpeed desc, TimeSent desc
) as CD
```

The #summary temporary table is creating summarised data about trips undertaken by a car. There can be multiple trips for each car with each trip having a start and stop time. The CarData table contains all the detailed car data like speed and position etc.

Please can you help?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: Yes. It says that the #summary.VehicleId, #summary.Start and #summary.Stop inside the subquery cannot be found.

Comment: Is it the case that you can have multiple records for a given vehicle between the start and stop?  I'm puzzled by the need for the top 1 in your example.

Comment: only need the latest record with the highest recorded speed, hence the top 1, works faster with the indexes than using an aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
    #summary
SET
    #summary.TopSpeed = CarData.TopSpeed ,
    #summary.SpeedTime = CarData.SpeedTime 
    ...
FROM
    #summary
INNER JOIN
    CarData
ON
    #summary.id = CarData.id AND (CarData.TimeSent BETWEEN #summary.Start AND #summary.Stop)
```

Comment: will try and get back to you.

Comment: i need the subquery to use the date range from the summary table. How do I plement this?

Comment: is TimeSent of type smalldatetime or datetime?

Comment: The range check needs to be inside the subquery to minimise the number of rows returned. The solution provided did not work.

Comment: then just substitute CarData above with a subquery and join on that subquery

Comment: the #summary table values are needed to constrain the data returned by the subquery ... and this is where the problem comes in ... these values cannot be seen inside the subquery (apparently)

Answer (score 0):

Where here's a way to do it, though I don't like it doing the subquery 3 times.  It's one of those cases where I hope someone has a better idea.

```
update #summary
  set TopSpeed = 
  (
      select top 1 TopSpeed
      from CarData
      where CarData.VehicleId = #summary.VehicleId 
      and CarData.TimeSent between #summary.Start and #summary.Stop
      order by CarData.TopSpeed desc, TimeSent desc
  ) 
  SpeedTime = 
  (
      select top 1 SpeedTime
      from CarData
      where CarData.VehicleId = #summary.VehicleId 
      and CarData.TimeSent between #summary.Start and #summary.Stop
      order by CarData.TopSpeed desc, TimeSent desc
  ) 
  SpeedDriver = 
  (
      select top 1 SpeedDriver
      from CarData
      where CarData.VehicleId = #summary.VehicleId 
      and CarData.TimeSent between #summary.Start and #summary.Stop
      order by CarData.TopSpeed desc, TimeSent desc
    )
```

Comment: The subquery needs the date range from the #summary table, therein lies the problem.

Comment: Updated with a somewhat brutal way to do it if you're married to top 1.  Would probably be easier with an aggregate function.  I don't know if top 1 makes it fast enough to compensate for doing it 3 times.